# Read XML - querying specific child element from multiple child elements

Tags: sql-server, xml

How do I query from this particular XML tree structure to obtain value under `Item Description 2` from below in SQL server?

```
<WorkOrderDTO>
  <WorkOrderAttributes>
    <WorkOrderAttributeDTO>
      <ID>0</ID>
      <Name>Item Description 2</Name>
      <Value>150</Value>
    </WorkOrderAttributeDTO>
    <WorkOrderAttributeDTO>
      <ID>0</ID>
      <Name>RX only Symbol</Name>
      <Value>Y</Value>
    </WorkOrderAttributeDTO>
```

I have tried;

```
SELECT 
[WorkOrderXML].value('(/WorkOrderDTO/WorkOrderAttributes/WorkOrderAttributeDTO/Name[@name="Item Description 2"][Value])[1]', 'varchar(max)')
FROM table
```

Unfortunately, I get a NULL value. The expected output should be `150`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please show your full *valid* XML, including any namespaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
value('(/WorkOrderDTO/WorkOrderAttributes/WorkOrderAttributeDTO[Name[text()="Item Description 2"]]/Value)[1]', 'varchar(max)')
```

Comment: Hello lptr, appreciate the response however unfortunately i still get a NULL response

Comment: … @ARJ… are there WorkOrderAttributeDTO nodes with Name= Item Descr 2 but missing the Value element?

Comment: My apologies lptr, i just noticed that there was a XML namespace defined in the structure. So i managed to add that into your query above and instead of achieving an output of "150", i got an output of "0Item Description 2150".